# Make $.ajax fail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is rather an odd question, but, I want to make $.ajax fail to check my fail trigger in it, I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trigger").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "text.php",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".log").html(data.slice(0, 1000));
                //alert("Load has been performed");
            },
            fail: function () {
                $(".msg").html("Something went wrong...");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And am calling this PHP code:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    return "bar";
}

print foo();

return false;
?>
```

and want to make sure that the `fail: ...` is working. How do I do this?

**EDIT**

I have amended the text.php to be this:

```
<?php
throw new LogicException("Failed");
```

Also:

```
<?php
header("HTTP://this.does.not.exist");
```

But this still shows in the `$(".log")` area even though it has failed.

Noticed I was using the fail function wrong, now amended my jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#trigger").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "text.php"
        }).done(function (data) {
            $(".log").html(data.slice(0, 1000));
        }).fail(function () {
            $(".msg").html("Something went wrong...");
        }).always(function () {
            alert("One way or another, we did it!");
        });
    });
});
```

Also if it helps, I am using these scripts for jQuery libraries:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried sending back a 500 server error code header? (rather than a 4xx client error)?

Comment: @STTLCU, yes, and it didn't work

Comment: Chat is available thanks to @pingul, [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84356/q-make-ajax-fail)

Comment: @SamSwift: Please add the solution to your question as an answer, rather than appending it to the question.

Comment: @Matt, I was simply adding this to credit pingul for his vast amounts of help

Comment: @SamSwift: The Stack Overflow way of giving someone credit is by accepting their answer... which you've already done, and by upvoting it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Change the `.fail` callback call to `.error` and
2. Try it by returning an error status code from your server like jeroen suggested,

   ```
   header("not-real.php", true, 404);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You could send a header returning an error.

For example:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Or of course have your script generate a fatal error ;-)

Comment: Why did I never think of that!

Comment: @SamSwift Does it make any difference to use the `error` callback instead of `fail`?

Comment: @pingul, what do you mean a callback? (Not meaning to sound stupid, just not been doing this very long!)

Comment: @SamSwift pingul is right, it seems there is no `fail` property, only a `fail()` method on the returned object. So you need `error: function() {}`.

Comment: There seems to exist a `fail` property, but in the docs it is used as a promise callback, and I'm a little bit unsure how it behaves in this context. So yes; change the `fail: function() {}` to `error: function() {}` as jeroen suggested and it should maybe work :)

Comment: @pingul, unfortunately it did not, I am using the jQuery windows 8.1 store app as ref and it said to use the fail function to catch errors...

Comment: @SamSwift Hmm... I have kinda hi-jacked jeroens comment section, so we shouldn't keep the discussion here. Could you update the question with the network response you are receiving, and we can talk in the chat if necessary.

Comment: @pingul, there is no response... It may be best to take this to chat